# How to extract MySQL data monthwise and daywise to populate table to draw graph using PHP libchart?

Tags: php, mysql, graph

I have a table that has rows like CALL_ID, Timestamp, Date, First_Name, Last_Name, Status and so on..

What I need to do is draw graphs based on the data, filtered according to their dates.
That is for the Month-to-date graph, I need to show the number of rows matching status=approved for each day of the month uptil current date.

And, for the Year-to-date graph, I need to show the number of rows matching Status=approved for each month of the year uptil current month.

My idea of doing it is this -

For Month-to-date:

```
$temp = date("Y-m-");
while($i<=date("d"))
{
$query = "SELECT call_id FROM main WHERE status='approved' AND date='".$temp.$i."'";
$result = mysql_query($query, $link) or die("",mysql_error());
$count[i]= mysql_num_rows($result);
}
```

For Date-to-year:

```
while ($i <= date("m"))
{
    $query = "SELECT call_id FROM main WHERE status='approved' AND date BETWEEN'".$today_y."-".$i."-01' AND '".$today_y."-".$i."-31";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $link) or die("",mysql_error());
    $count_y[i]= mysql_num_rows($result);
}
```

And then I was thinking of pushing these counts present in the array by a "while" loop into another temporary tables (one for MTD and one for YTD) and then using PHP libchart to draw the graph from those tables.

Is there a better way to do this? Or is this the only way?

Comment: PHP isn't javascript. Variables has dollar sign ($) before their names

Comment: The variables DO have $ sign before their names.

Comment: `while(i` ..... check it again

Comment: Ah, thanks, will correct it, could you please also help me out for the better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this a lot easier just using mysql and getting rid of a lot of your php loops. Something like this for month-to-date:

```
$query="SELECT COUNT(call_id) as 'num_records', date FROM main WHERE status='approved' AND CONCAT(YEAR(date),MONTH(date)) = CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW())) GROUP BY date
```

That query will give a row showing the date and the total records for that day, for every day month-to-date.

Comment: if you dont mind, could you please explain the query performed? And if you don't mind telling how I can perform a similar query for Year-To-Date as well. i am just a beginner and want to learn. Thanks :)

Comment: Sure I can try to explain it. The `COUNT()` part will select the number of records returned that meet the WHERE conditions. If you notice the very end of the query `GROUP BY date`, that tells mysql to group every row together as long as they have the same date. So, if you had 5 entries all with a date of '2011-05-02' for example, you would get one row back with a count of 5 instead. Then `CONCAT()` function is just used to add strings together like `.` does in PHP. [This tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlgroupby.php) might help.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very clear explanation :) So I perform a similar query for Date-to-year as well. Would this be correct?: `SELECT COUNT(call_id) as 'num_month_records' WHERE date BETWEEN CONCAT(YEAR(NOW),1)) AND CONCAT(YEAR(NOW),MONTH(NOW)) GROUP BY date`

Comment: Since you just want the same year, you don't need `CONCAT` anymore. You can do `SELECT COUNT(call_id) as 'num_month_records' WHERE YEAR(date) = YEAR(NOW()) GROUP BY date`

Comment: Note: there is one downside to this... you will not get any results on a day where there were NO records at all.